# Is there an application or plugin for OSMAnd to retrieve trail signage and information?

Tags: historical

Is the information written on trail signs publicly available in a central place so that when I am out hiking or biking on a trail and come across a sign, I could get the same information on my phone via an app or OSMAnd plugin?  Additionally, if it were to be available, it would be useful if it were downloadable beforehand either along a route or within a polygon.